# Confused about Directory.GetFiles

Tags: c#

I've read the docs about the `Directory.GetPath` search pattern and how it is used, because I noticed that `*.dll` finds both `test.dll` and `test.dll_20170206`. That behavior is documented

Now, I have a program that lists files in a folder based on a user-configured mask and processes them. I noticed that masks like `*.txt` lead to the above mentioned "problem" as expected.

However, the mask `fixedname.txt` also causes `fixedname.txt_20170206` or the like to appear in the list, even though the documentation states this only occurs

> When you use the asterisk wildcard character in a searchPattern such as "*.txt"

Why is that?

PS: I just checked: Changing the file mask to `fixednam?.txt` does not help even though the docs say

> When you use the question mark wildcard character, this method returns only files that match the specified file extension. For example, given two files, "file1.txt" and "file1.txtother", in a directory, a search pattern of "file?.txt" returns just the first file, whereas a search pattern of "file*.txt" returns both files.

Comment: I can reproduce this issue with `*` prefixed, but not `?` - `?????????.txt` only matches `fixedname.txt`

Comment: I can't reproduce this either. Tried this 2 lines: `var a=Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\temp", "fixedname.txt");` and `var a=Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\temp", "fixednam?.txt");` and they  just return one file,not `fixedname.txt_20170206`

Comment: Funny... I tried your question with the files `"Rename-Plan.txt"` and `"Rename-Plan.txt12"`. There is a difference between patterns with `"-"` and patterns without it. `"Rename-Plan.txt"` returns 1, `"Rename-*.txt"` return 1, `"Rename*.txt"` returns 2, `"Rename?Plan.txt"` returns 1, `"Rename?????.txt"` returns 2. you get the pattern I guess

Comment: Thorsten, as this may be a real issue in .NET, please state the exact platform and version(s) you found it on. Also, please create and post a [MCVE]

Comment: Well, funny indeed. I've created a sample program and it does not show the error. On the other hand: the same code in a Windows Service creates a problem. I'll investigate further and come back to you.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a solution you may transform the filter pattern into a regular expression by replacing `*` by `(.*)` and `?` by `.`. You also have to escape some pattern characters like the dot. Then you check each filename you got from `Directory.GetFiles` against this regular expression. Keep in mind to not only check if it is a match but that the match length is equal to the length of the filename. Otherwise you get the same results as before.

Comment: I've actually done that before and it worked. I still wonder why in this particular tool I have this problem when I can't reproduce it otherwise...

Comment: Could you go onto more detail regarding *... but that the match length is equal to the length of the filename.*?

Comment: Basically `match.Length` has to be the same as `filename.Length`.

Answer (score 1):

GetFiles uses pattern serach, it searches for all names in path ending with the letters specified.

You can write code similar to below to get only .txt extension file

```
  foreach (string strFileName in Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\\test\","*.txt"))
            {
                string extension;
                extension = Path.GetExtension(strFileName);

                if (extension != ".txt")
                    continue;
                else
                {
                    //processed the file
                }
            }
```

Comment: All nice and well if you *know* what you're looking for. Impossible if the user is allowed to define the mask himself.